# How to go about finding the average, min, max and the range of the numbers of the input in python?

Tags: python, max, average, min

```
a = int(input('How many numbers do you want today? '))
for i in range(0,a):
    num=int(input('enter a number'))
    print(num)
```

> now i want the average, min, max and the range of the numbers entered,
>   what do you do next?

Comment: `a = np.array(map(float,input("Enter a list of numbers, separated by comma's:").split(",")));print(a.max(),a.min(),a.average())`

Comment: Can you please try explaining more in detail what you tried and what you expect ?

Comment: @ChetanVasudevan i have asked the user for input of numbers, so now i want the average of the numbers they have made an input of, the min, and the maximum among that input of numbers.

Comment: As soon as you rewrite the `num` variable, python forgets about its old value. Before the loop, create an empty list and append each number to it. Then, after the user has passed all their numbers to the script and the loop has finished, run the calculations on the numbers in the list. See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html for how to use the append method on lists.

Comment: @C.Kamath, did you mention to do without using list or something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have not provided us with any conditions of what to use or what not to use. Below is something that you can try

```
number_input = input("Enter the number")
l=[]
for i in range(0,int(number_input)):
    l.append(i)
#print(l) #for the values storing I use list here
print("The maximum is:"+str(max(l)))
print("The minimum is:"+str(min(l)))
print("The average is:"+str(sum(l)/len(l)))
```

> The output would look like:
>
> Enter the number 10
>
> The maximum is:9  The minimum is:0   The average is:4.5

Answer (score 1):

Input all numbers by space.
In Python3 map no longer returns a list, So we need to wrap it in a list call.

```
s = input()
numbers = list(map(int, s.split()))
avg = sum(numbers)/len(numbers)
min_val = min(numbers)
max_val = max(numbers)
```

[Output Image]
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVvM4.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156127/discussion-between-chetan-vasudevan-and-sagar).